# Как из aplication сделать библиотеку для повторного использования?

Tags: android

Собственно я создал приложение которое перелистывает карты. Куча методов, прекрасно работает и половина логики завязана на MainActivity. Но тут меня просят сделать из этого чуда библиотеку. Чтобы бы использовать в другом приложении. Как это можно организовать? Как app конвертить в library я уже понял. Но как этим пользоваться если у меня многое в MainActivity описано? Это надо все переделывать? Переделывать как?

Comment: вынести все из `Activity` в новые классы. Разве это не очевидно?

Answer (score 1):

Выноси все методы в классы, сделай какой-нибудь класс главный в котором инициализируй все, что тебе нужно и т.д.